# Curl downloads files with html body

Tags: download, curl, raw

The issue is when using curl to download a file that is readable like .ini or .txt it downloads the file but when inspecting its content it has a html body with the original file's code embedded inside.

-> A fix is to upload these files to github and use the "raw" download link -> Would anyone know how I can configure my own server to do the same?

Next does anyone know how to download a .lnk (shortcut) file without making it unreadable. I can't say much but on it works and when downloaded it does not, it's not even displayed as a shortcut file anymore?

Comment: what webserver are you using, and have you installed a web application on it?

Comment: @FrankThomas Plesk Onyx and its a website on a linux ubuntu vm created with plesk